# Is it possible to call assign with iterators from a different kind of container?

Tags: stl, containers, assign

Is it possible to assign a vector `v` the values of a list `l` by using

```
 v.assign(l.begin(), l.end());
```

? If so, what are the limitations on the kind of container/supported iterator that can be used?

Comment: Did you read any documentation vector's constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The limitations are best described in the documentation - in this case the iterators need to be *input iterators*.